# css: centering nav on page automatically when new pages are added

Tags: css

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tmjuv/

Basically, I want the nav block to be centered on the page. If the number of pages were static, I could just add a width and do a `margin:0 auto` (example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tmjuv/1/)); however, in this case, it will be for a theme so the nav will have to be centered no matter how many pages the user adds. Is this possible with only css?

Comment: Why not wrap it in a div with a width and have the ul margin: 0 auto?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add, I can't touch the source code. I'm modifying a theme on the Ning platform which restricts users from accessing the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/meo/tmjuv/8/

It require the UL to be wrapped. If its not in your actual surce code, since you can't change it, you gonna need some JS to do it. I think there is no pure css solution to this.
but it requires the browser to understand `inline-block`. Whats not the case of IE6.

Comment: this is also good but again it doesn't work in ie7 unfortunately. =/

Comment: it does in IE7 (if you apply this: http://grasshopperpebbles.com/css/css-inline-block-ie7-hack/). it does not in IE6

Answer (score 3):

Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/tmjuv/10/

It uses `display: table`, and works without changing the structure of your html code.

I didn't look to see if this example runs in all browsers.

EDIT:

Look at this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/tmjuv/12/. It works with a transparent background-color of the `ul` and background-colors for the `li`s. You can try if this works in all browsern (unfortunatly I have only FF and IE9 on this pc ..)

Comment: i think it should, nice one! +1

Comment: ok i have just checked. It will not work in IE6 & 7 but it does in safari, FF, IE8&9 and chrome

Comment: Hmm, this is what I thought that it might not run in all browsers :-(

Comment: that's a good solution but it doesn't work in ie7 unfortunately. anyway we can get it to work in ie7 too? i can't think of anything.

Comment: @J82: I don't think that it will work in IE7 because IE7 doesn't support ´´display: table´´ and ´´display: inline-block´´ and I think this two are the only way to center your navigation without changing the structure of your html.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `<ul>` to `text-align: center` and the `<li>`s to `display: inline-block;`, that should give you the effect you want.

- http://jsfiddle.net/pauldwaite/QJgT8/1/

Not entirely sure it’ll work in older versions of IE though — I *think* `inline-block` was only supported on block-level elements in IE from version 8.

Comment: i think he wants the nav block to be centered (according to the example) not the navigation elements. It will work in IE7 but not IE6

Comment: @meo: oh, I see what you mean. Yup, it wouldn’t centre the containing block.